# IIS, APACHE, YAWS runtime environment

Tags: apache, iis, yaws

Recently I gone through a an article explaining potentiality of YAWS server and the number of requests it processes per second. It was mentioned that YAWS can handle 80K requests per second and it also run in multi threaded environment to improve request processing limit.

How can we compare IIS, Apache with YAWS? Which one will process maximum requests? Can I find any comparisons somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Check this link out:

```
http://www.sics.se/~joe/apachevsyaws.html
```

Link to Yaws vs apache

You see that Yaws handles 80000 concurrent requests (and continuing) while apache fails at around 4000 connections.
 This is because Yaws runs on the Erlang/OTP VM. Processes belong to this machine and not the operating system. Erlang has been highly customised for concurrent programming. Infact, other erlang web applications like:***mochiweb***,***webmachine***, e.t.c are much more powerful than apache when it comes to handling many concurrent requests.
 Yaws web server scales better than any web server i know of today. With the ability to create ***appmods***, you can create Erlang Applications that communicate over http protocol, making use of the power of yaws.

Yaws home page is:

```
http://yaws.hyber.org/
```

. 
Actually, Yaws gets its power from OTP (Open Telecom Platform). This set of powerful libraries found at

```
http://erlang.org/
```

, has the most advanced design patterns such as fail over systems, supervision trees, finite state machines, event handlers, e.t.c, You should actually start using erlang for your next web application!!!!